# How to set some sort of array for VBA find/replace scripts

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

UPDATED SCRIPT I'M USING THAT CAUSES LOCKUP...I tried replacing the (Replace:=wdReplaceOne) with (Replace:=wdReplaceAll), but still no such luck:

```
Option Explicit
'Dim strMacroName As String
 Dim spellingcorrectionsrep As Long

 Public Sub SpellingReview()
 Dim oShell, MyDocuments
```

'Declaring the MyDocs filepath:
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    MyDocuments = oShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
    Set oShell = Nothing

```
'   Set values for variables of the actual word to find/replace
spellingsuggestionsrep = 0
spellingcorrectionsrep = 0

'   Replacements

SpellingCorrections "dog", "dog (will be changed to cat)", False, True

'    END SEARCHING DOCUMENT AND DISPLAY MESSAGE

MsgBox spellingcorrectionsrep

'strMacroName = "Spelling Review"
'Call LogMacroUsage(strMacroName)

 End Sub
  Sub SpellingCorrections(sInput As String, sReplace As String, MC As Boolean, MW As     Boolean)

'   Set Selection Search Criteria
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
With Selection
     With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Text = sInput
    .Replacement.Text = sReplace
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchCase = MC
    .MatchWholeWord = MW
End With
Do While .Find.Execute = True
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If

    If .Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne) = True Then
    spellingcorrectionsrep = spellingcorrectionsrep + 1
    End If
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
  Loop
  End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: is your dictionary a fixed size, with fixed values (so you could hard code each word) or is it taken from some where else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use it as a common procedure?

```
Option Explicit

Dim wordRep As Long

Public Sub SpellingReview()
    Dim oShell, MyDocuments

    wordRep = 0

    SpellingCorrections "Dog", "Dog (will be changed to DOG)", False, True

    MsgBox wordRep
End Sub

Sub SpellingCorrections(sInput As String, sReplace As String, MC As Boolean, MW As Boolean)
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=sInput, Forward:=True, Format:=True, _
           MatchWholeWord:=MW, MatchCase:=MC) = True
           wordRep = wordRep + 1
        Loop
    End With

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Text = sInput
        .Replacement.Text = sReplace
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = MC
        .MatchWholeWord = MW
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and very simple. Many thanks to you my friend!

Comment: Is there anyway to do something similar to my the code at the beginning of my first post?  I tried to set it up similar to this reply but it doesn't like the "wordrep = wordrep + 1" which I need to keep track of the results as it increments each "found" instance, which I end up writing out to an INI file to keep track.

Comment: Did you declare this at the top ? `Dim wordrep as Long` or do you mean the total number of replacements done?

Comment: That's what I meant . . however, this may be a stupid question, but how can I make it so that the wordRep variable is passed back/available in the main sample sub as that is where the rest of my script will be?

Comment: declare it on top, outside the procedure, as I have done above.

Comment: Missed that part of the code.  I appreciate your help so much.  Many thanks and blessings to you!

Comment: Mostly.  If you use the word "fox" and replace it with "fox (should not use fox)" it ends up replacing it two or three times each . . Not sure how to get around that.

Comment: If you just do the word fox you end up with this:  fox (should not use fox) (should not use fox (should not use fox)) . . . it's looping through and hitting fox three times each

Comment: I changed .Wrap = wdFindContinue to .Wrap = wdFindStop and that seems to have helped . . going to test a bit more

Comment: OK, yes I got it working . . the only thing that it's NOT doing is highlighting. I'm using <pre><code> .ClearFormatting .Highlight = False .Replacement.ClearFormatting .Replacement.Highlight = True</code></pre>

Comment: So it's working and tracking the correct results, however it stopped the highlighting effect.  Any way to keep the highlighting?

Comment: Sorry had stepped out for couple of hours... Insert `Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True` in ReplaceText Function

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the 'code' Do While .Find.Execute = True 'code'

Comment: <code>Sub SpellingSuggestions(sInput As String, sReplace As String, MC As Boolean, MW As Boolean) ' Set Selection Search Criteria Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory With Selection With .Find .ClearFormatting .Replacement.ClearFormatting .Text = sInput .Replacement.Text = sReplace .Forward = True .Wrap = wdFindStop .Format = False .MatchWildcards = False .MatchCase = MC .MatchWholeWord = MW End With</code>

Comment: Yup that's what I was trying and many variations of that.  I tried putting the selection.find.highlight = true above too and still no go.

Comment: The above is tested and tried. Did you copy the code as it is?

Comment: I did copy the code.  It just switches between a mouse icon and hour glass, locks up word, and I have to restart.

Comment: I just tested it again. It works :) See this sample http://wikisend.com/download/252150/Sample.docm. Run the macro `SpellingReview`

Comment: If you use the word "ibag" and replace word as "ibag (will be changed to iBAAG) it freezes it up.

Comment: You sir, are a man among men!  I appreciate your help and I am really grateful for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Creating an Array to store the information isn't too hard

```
Dim Dict() As Variant
' Integer ReplacementCount, String FindText, Boolean MatchCase, Boolean MatchWholeWord, String ReplaceText
Dict = Array( _
            Array(0, "Word", True, True, "word"), _
            Array(0, "Word1", True, True, "word1"), _
            Array(0, "Word2", True, True, "word2"), _
            Array(0, "Word3", True, True, "word3") _
        )
```

Using this you could loop through each item and store the replacement counter in the same array.

```
For Index = LBound(Dict) To UBound(Dict)
    Do While ReplaceStuffFunction(WithArguments) = True
       Dict(Index)(0) = Dict(Index)(0) + 1
    Loop
Next Index
```

When I tried your first example code it didn't seem to replace ALL instances, just one per run of the sub so either I did it wrong or something not right (or its not meant to do it)

Comment: I coudln't quite get this working right, but I appreciate you're reply very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
'In this example, I used two arrays to shorten formal hospital names
'Define two arrays (I used FindWordArray and ReplacewordArray)
'The position of the word (by comma) in each arrays correspond to each other

Dim n as long
Dim FindWordArray, ReplaceWordArray As String 'Change information pertinent to your needs
Dim FWA() As String 'Find words array created by split function
Dim RWA() As String 'Replace array created by split function
Dim HospitalName As String 'This is the string to find and replace

FindWordArray = ("Hospital,Center,Regional,Community,University,Medical") 'change data here separate keep the quotes and separate by commas
FWA = Split(FindWordArray, ",")
ReplaceWordArray = ("Hosp,Cntr,Reg,Com,Uni,Med") 'change data here keep the quotes but separate by commas
RWA = Split(ReplaceWordArray, ",")
'Loop through each of the arrays
For n = LBound(FWA) To UBound(FWA)
    HospitalName = Replace(HospitalName, FWA(n), RWA(n))
Next n
```